# Architecting business collections with private setter in in service layer

Tags: c#

Usually I thought this code is a good design:

Look at the private setter for the collection. So nobody can assign a new collection from outside the schoolclass object.

```
public class Schoolclass
    {
        public Schoolclass()
        {
            Pupils = new List<Pupil>();
        }            

        public int SchoolclassId { get; set; }
        public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }

        public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; private set; }
    }
```

Regarding this style my data fetching method does not work anymore:

Service Layer doing calls to the SQLite Data Provider:

BL:

```
public IEnumerable<Schoolclass> GetAdministrationData()
        {
            var schoolclasses = adminDataProvider.GetSchoolclassList();
            foreach (Schoolclass s in schoolclasses)
            {
                var pupils = adminDataProvider.GetPupilsBySchoolclassId(s.SchoolclassId);
                s.Pupils = pupils;

                foreach (Pupil p in pupils)
                {
                    var documents = adminDataProvider.GetDocumentsByPupilId(p.Id);
                    p.Documents = documents;
                }
            }
            return schoolclasses;
        }
```

If I would have now a private setter the above aggregating would not work.

So do I have another choice? Or should I stick to my loading technic ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you you have loads of options:

Add the pupils to the already created list.

```
var pupils = adminDataProvider.GetPupilsBySchoolclassId(s.SchoolclassId);
s.Pupils.AddRange(pupils);

foreach (Pupil p in pupils)
{
   var documents = adminDataProvider.GetDocumentsByPupilId(p.Id);
   p.Documents.AddRange(documents);
}
```

Note that it is kind of bad form to expose `List<T>` - Better to expose `Collection<T>` though then you will have to add the items one by one.

If you write you guy like this:

```
public class Schoolclass
{
    public Schoolclass()
    {
        Pupils = new BindingList<Pupil>(); 
            // binding list descends from Collection<T> 

    }            

    public int SchoolclassId { get; set; }
    public string SchoolclassCode { get; set; }

    public Collection<Pupil> Pupils { get; private set; }
}
```

Of course there are a 1,000,000 ways and more to write this and the loader. I favor lazy loading myself. Then when you only load them when someone asks for the pupils.

Comment: I return IEnumerable<T> so I can not do .AddRange()

Comment: That is not what you code sample has :) You have other options. Lazy loading would be my choice, internal private scoping might work if your loader is in the same assembly.

Comment: why is List vs Collection bad? Never have read that. And it does not make sense. I prefer eager loading all because the data I have is small furthermore I use WPF which is about data binding. plug in a collection of pupils to a selected schoolclass causes binding trouble like I experienced in former times. The best is to return IEnumerable<T> because its an interface.

Comment: List is not bad, just exposing it. Read more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/faq-why-does-donotexposegenericlists-recommend-that-i-expose-collection-lt-t-gt-instead-of-list-lt-t-gt-david-kean.aspx

Comment: this link really can`t be used generally. My requirements are totally low, so I do not need to override anything. A List<T> is total fine in my case.

Comment: @Neil Another drawback with your advise "I favor lazy loading" is, that everytime I select a schoolclass and the pupils gets added to the immutable collection. So I will add again and again the same pupils to the collection which is increasing more and more. So everytime a schoolclass is selected I have to Clear() the elements in the collection of pupils...

Comment: @lisa - no you only load the first time - if is already loaded don't worry. Using `List<T>` is not bad - exposing as a `List<T>` is bad - if you expose as `IEnumerable<T>` you are fine  - since if you need to add capabilities to your list you can still expose it as `IEnumerable<T>` but implement it with something else like `BindingList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of [immutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable).  Your `List<Pupil>` property is still mutable, even with a private setter.

I can't set your Pupils property directly:

`myclass.Pupils = new List<Pupil>();`

... but I can *modify* it:

```
var myClass = new SchoolClass();
myClass.Pupils.Add(new Pupil());
```

Here is a good article discussing different types of immutability in C#:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx

Comment: thanks for the wiki link it has no c# :P I am just trying to categorize the post of eric lippert into my direct private setter problem. You say I can modify it... with .Add() Well is that then ok for you ? Would Add not harm immutability ? As it is not changing/setting a new list it sounds immutable to me.